Parbox with multiple baselineskip height
I'm defining a chapter style, and I'd like to print the chapter title within a \parbox. I'd like the \parbox take a vertical space which is in any case an exact multiple of \baselineskip.
In the following example, however, the two-lines \parbox is smaller than 2\baselineskip. Why, and how can I fix it?
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\myparbox
\sbox\myparbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{This is a one-line parbox\strut}}
\usebox{\myparbox}

Height of the one-line parbox: \the\dimexpr\ht\myparbox+\dp\myparbox\relax

\sbox\myparbox{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{This is a \\ two-lines parbox\strut}}
\usebox{\myparbox}

Height of the two-lines parbox: \the\dimexpr\ht\myparbox+\dp\myparbox\relax

\end{document}


You can add a strut at the beginning and end.  However, TeX only uses \baselineskip when the baselines are close enough.  Otherwise it adds \lineskip between the bottom of one box and the top of the next.

The first line of your two-lines parbox has the height of a T only, but the parbox of the one-line parbox has the depth and height of the \strut:
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\myparbox
\sbox\myparbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{This is a one-line parbox\strut}}
\usebox{\myparbox}

Height of the one-line parbox: \the\dimexpr\ht\myparbox+\dp\myparbox\relax

\sbox\myparbox{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\strut This is a \\ two-lines parbox\strut}}
\usebox{\myparbox}

Height of the two-lines parbox: \the\dimexpr\ht\myparbox+\dp\myparbox\relax

\end{document}

